# Check if keys in a hashmap are all in an array

Tags: ruby, hashmap

Say I have the array `a = ["a","b"]`
And the hashmap `{"hello" => "world", "a" => "d"}`

That would return false because "hello" is not in the array 'a'.

The hashmap: `{"a" => "hello", "a" => "world"}` is fine.

Is there a way to do this without manually doing all the work? eg: find if the hashmap keys are a subset of the array?

Comment: You should refer to the object `{"hello" => "world", "a" => "d"}` as a "hash" (i.e, instance of `Hash`). "hashmap" (aka "hash table") refers to the data structure.

Comment: `{"a" => "hello", "a" => "world"}` is not "fine", as hashes cannot have duplicate keys. :-) You could also write `hash.values_at(*a).size == hash.size`, but `)hash.keys-a).empty?` is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
(hash.keys - a).empty?
# if returns true means all keys present in array.
# if returns false means all keys are not present in array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
keys = hashmap.keys
(keys - a).empty?
```

Is result 'keys - a' is empty - it means that all keys are in array

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this

```
a = ["a","b"]
b = {"hello" => "world", "a" => "d"}

(a-b.keys).empty?
```